# Delegate with Variadic Templates

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

When an event fires (key press, mouse, etc.) my application will call delegate functions that have registered for that event.

Below is the implementation. I am trying to make the 'invoke' function (`()`) a variadic template so that I can pass any parameters to it. But with my current setup below its not possible.

Any ideas how I can achieve using variadic templates in this design?

**Edit** Changed code

```
template <typename... params>
class EventDelegate
{
public:
    typedef std::function<int(params...)> EDelegate;

    EventDelegate(EDelegate delegate) : delegate(delegate)
    {

    }

    int operator()(params...) const
    {
        return delegate(params...);
    }

private:
    EDelegate delegate;
};

// Not valid because template params are not specified. But each EventDelegate can take different params
std::unordered_multimap<int, EventDelegate> evtRegistry; 

// Example

class Foo
{
public:
    int onLeftClick(GUID sender, Point pos);
    int onKeyDown(char key);
};

// Usage 

... 

evtRegistry[1] = EventDelegate(std::bind(&Foo::onLeftClick, myFoo, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
evtRegistry[2] = EventDelegate(std::bind(&Foo::onKeyDown, myFoo, std::placeholders::_1));
```

Event handling:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK Win32App::wndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            auto registeredCmps = evtRegistry.equal_range(EVT_INIT);
            for (auto iter = registeredCmps.first; iter != registeredCmps.second; iter++)
                iter->second();
        }
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            auto registeredCmps = evtRegistry.equal_range(EVT_EXIT);
            for (auto iter = registeredCmps.first; iter != registeredCmps.second; iter++)
                iter->second(someParam, someOtherParam);
        }
        break;
        ...
```

Comment: Unclear how you want to call `EventDelegate` without knowing which parameter to pass...

Comment: @Jarod42 woops thats a typo. I'll fix it now. That is my previous implementation

Comment: Its not clear how you will distinguish between events when iterating through the elements in the evtRegistry.  How can you call the function without knowing the template instanciation?

Comment: And how do you expect to use `evtRegistry[x]` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 Please see edit for event handling. Note evtRegistry is a `unordered_multimap`

Answer (score 0):

My first inclination, and perhaps the simplest answer here is to create separate data structures for each event type.  For example:

```
std::vector< EventDelegate< GUID, Point > > clickRegistry
std::vector< EventDelegate< char > > keyDownRegistry
```

Usage

```
clickRegistry.push_back( EventDelegate(std::bind(&Foo::onLeftClick, myFoo, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2)) );
```

Although why creating a separate delegate here when you could use`std::function`directly is unclear. (I could see adding a bunch of other utility to the Delegate class at a future point, and maybe that is your intent).

What are you trying to achieve with a single data structure holding all registered events?

Comment: "What are you trying to achieve with a single data structure holding all registered events?", what every programmer wants to achieve; Simplicity, Elegance and Perfection, duh